# chemmacros: Using \mbox{} within \iupac{} leads to @x in running title

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros

I am using *chemmacros* in my thesis and have the following problem:

When using `\mbox{}` within `\iupac{}` in a `\section{}` or `\subsection{}` it leads to "@x " being printed in the running title. Also, the following error messages are produced:

> Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
>   Missing number, treated as zero. \end{document}

However, `\mbox{}` works fine outside of `\iupac{}` without any error messages.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,open=right]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
    \section{It works fine here: awe\mbox{-}some}
    \cleardoublepage
    \section{It does not work here: \iupac{2,2,6,6\mbox{-}Tetramethylpiperidine}}
\end{document}
```

Why is this so important? Compound names should never have a linebreak after numbers. However, in my thesis there are some very long names that are sometimes split like this:

> ... 1,1'-
>   biphenyl ...

I appreciate your help!

Kind regards,
basseur

Comment: “Compound names should never have a linebreak after numbers.” is this your opinion or is this a IUPAC recommendation (source?)

Comment: @clemens I am quite certain I read it somewhere back in 2014, but of course, I cannot find it anymore. So let's call it my own opinion. ;) I came across this [IUPAC project](http://www.iupac.org/project/2014-003-2-800). Since there is no visible progress, I have mailed the task group leader.

Comment: I have actually received an answer and could forward it to your email address. It is quite interesting stuff and basically supports what I said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `\mbox` is not usually considered to be fragile, in this context it is, due to the processing done by `\iupac`.

You might use `\protect\mbox{-}`, but I wouldn't recommend it. Rather define a new macro for this hyphen:

```
\documentclass[twoside,open=right]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nbh}{}{\mbox{-}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\section{It works here: \iupac{2,2,6,6\protect\mbox{-}Tetramethylpiperidine}}

\section{It works here: \iupac{2,2,6,6\nbh Tetramethylpiperidine}}

\parbox[t]{0pt}{It works here: \iupac{2,2,6,6\protect\mbox{-}Tetramethylpiperidine}}
\hfill
\parbox[t]{0pt}{It works here: \iupac{2,2,6,6\nbh Tetramethylpiperidine}}
\hfill\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

As you see from the zero width boxes (to force hyphenation at all feasible points), the `\mbox{-}` will not allow breaks after it, whereas `\nbh` does.

[image]

As the package author suggests, one can also add a shorthand:

```
\NewChemIUPACShorthand{=}{\nbh}
```

that allows to input the compound as `2,2,2,6=Tetramethylpiperidine`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[twoside,open=right]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nbh}{}{\mbox{-}\nobreak\hspace{0pt}}
\NewChemIUPACShorthand{=}{\nbh}

\begin{document}

\section{It works here: \iupac{2,2,6,6=Tetramethylpiperidine}}

\parbox[t]{0pt}{It works here: \iupac{2,2,6,6=Tetramethylpiperidine}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And maybe even `\NewChemIUPACShorthand={\nbh}` and then `\iupac{2,2,6,6=Tetramethylpiperidine}` (or similar)

Comment: @clemens That's great. The feature request stands. `;-)`

Comment: I'll add something to the next release

Comment: Very nice! While we are at it: `\iupac` is supposed to add hyphens after closing parentheses when a line break is necessary. However, it also adds one between two closing parentheses.
see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZZz3.jpg

Comment: @basseur This should be raised on the GitHub site for `chemmacros`: https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros

Comment: @egreg Good point. Done.

Comment: @basseur Maybe adding the source code would be better.